# Java How to move between SurfaceViews

Tags: java, android, surfaceview

I'm developing a game right now and I'm having a problem on how to move between Main Menu and the gameplay itself. So when the game starts, it will set `MainMenuPanel` as the first View. Then, I'll use `canvas.draw` to a button in the MainMenu, when it is pressed it will go to the `GamePanel`.

Is there a way that I can use setContentView again in `MainMenuPanel` class?
Or is there any other way to do so? 
Thanks!

P.S. I've also thought using `ViewGroup`, but after I read the documentations I still don't get the idea how to use it.

MainActivity :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    GamePanel gp = new GamePanel(this);
    MainPanel mp = new MainPanel(this);
    //ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup)(gp.getParent());

    //Remove title
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    //Set fullscreen
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    setContentView(mp);

    }
}
```

MainMenuPanel :

```
public class MainMenuPanel extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback{
public MainMenuPanel(Context context){
    super(context);

    //Add callback to the surfaceview to intercept events
    getHolder().addCallback(this);

    setFocusable(true);
}
@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format,int width, int height){}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder){
}

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder){
}
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){
    if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN ){
        //Code to move to GamePanel
        }
        return true;
    }
    if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
        return true;
    }
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
}
}
```

GamePanel:

```
public class GamePanel extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback{
private MainThread thread;
public GamePanel(Context context){
    super(context);

    //Add callback to the surfaceview to intercept events
    getHolder().addCallback(this);

    //Make GamePanel focusable so it can handle events
    setFocusable(true);
}
@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format,int width, int height){}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder){
}

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder){
}

}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's not much point in using two SurfaceViews unless you've got them in separate Activities.  (See e.g. [Android Breakout](https://github.com/fadden/android-breakout), which uses View UI in one Activity for the main menu, but GLSurfaceView in a second Activity for the game itself.)

Since you're using SurfaceView for the menu and the game in a single Activity, there's no reason to have two separate SurfaceView subclasses.  There's no reason to subclass SurfaceView at all, really, though for some reason many examples continue to do so.

Create a single SurfaceView, and have both MainMenuPanel and GamePanel draw on it.

Comment: wow I never know that there can be 2 activity class. Thanks for the explanation. One thing that bothers me, so for example I have instatiated the classes and draw it for main menu objects (such as play_btn, option_btn,hi-score,etc), and when I go to the game itself, I'll just stop drawing those main menu objects and start drawing the game objects right? But, doesn't those objects in main menu will still take up memories even though it is not drawn? Is there any way to clear it? Thanks!

Comment: Assuming you have the data in Bitmaps, you can use `Bitmap.recycle()` to discard the pixel data. Or just drop all references to it and wait for the garbage collector to do its thing.

Comment: oh I see. Just one more thing, about what you just said "drop all references to it", what does it mean? can you please explain? Thanks

Comment: Don't have a reference to the object in any fields or local variables.